# MySql - Sort persons by name and partner

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, grouping

I'm dealing with the following problem in a MySQL/PHP web application:

A table of persons looking having the columns:

ID, firstname, surname, idOfPartner, street, zipCode

should be ordered by the surname of the person which should be then followed by the partner of the person so the result would look like

Person A
Partner of person A (no matter what the surname starts with)
Person B
Partner of person B
...

I'm currently doing a simple ORDER BY surname and the putting them together in the PHP code.

At the moment my query is simply

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY surname, firstname
```

The rest is done in the php code which is really slow.

Can this even be achieved only in the database? And is it better performance wise?

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: At the moment my query is simply SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY surname, firstname. The rest is done in the php code which is really slow

Comment: What index(es) do you have on the customers table?

Comment: I have a primary key on the id and the idOfPartner is a nullable int with an index and foreign key to the id of the partner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's build this up.

The list of persons, without partners, is:

```
SELECT a.surname, a.firstname,
       a.surname sortsurname, a.firstname sortfirstname, a.id sortid,
       0 role
  FROM person a
```

Now we fetch the partners of the persons. In this JOIN the b is the partner.

```
SELECT b.surname, b.firstname,
       a.surname sortsurname, a.firstname sortfirstname, a.id sortid,
       1 role
  FROM person a
  JOIN person b ON b.id = a.idofpartner
```

Now we combine these two tables with UNION ALL and sort the whole mess on the sorting names and the role

```
SELECT surname, firstname, role FROM (
SELECT a.surname, a.firstname,
       a.surname sortsurname, a.firstname sortfirstname, a.id sortid,
       0 role
  FROM person a
              UNION ALL
SELECT b.surname, b.firstname,
       a.surname sortsurname, a.firstname sortfirstname, a.id sortid,
       1 role
  FROM person a
  JOIN person b ON b.id = a.idofpartner
 ) both
ORDER BY sortsurname, sortfirstname, sortid, role
```

The trick here is to assign a role of 0 to the person and a role of 1 to the partner, and to create extra columns in the result set to allow sorting.  I added the sortid parameter to deal with the case where more than one person shares a name.